# When I use _mm512_gf2p8affine_epi64_epi8 from the GFNI instruction set and add a return value to this function, it results in an error

Tags: c, avx512

My hardware supports instruction sets. It can run without adding a return value, but when adding one, it throws an error Illegal instruction (core dumped).

Makefile is as follows:

```
CC      = icc
CFLAGS      = -g  -march=native -mgfni -mavx512f 

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o $(BIN) $(OBJS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(BIN)
```

I have tried many examples, but they all result in errors. For example, https://github.com/WojciechMula/toys/tree/master/avx512-galois.

Comment: *It can run without adding a return value* - Sounds like it just got optimized away, so the corresponding asm instruction *didn't* have to run.  Illegal instruction on an AVX-512 instruction is a sure sign that your CPU or emulator doesn't support AVX-512.  (Or your OS is so old that it didn't enable it.)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512 - you haven't told us what CPU you have, so check the list yourself.

Comment: If `-march=native` didn't enable `-mavx512f` already, that's another way to tell your CPU doesn't support AVX-512.

Comment: I have tried on two machines: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz/Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5115 CPU @ 2.40GHz/CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009.@PeterCordes

Comment: Those CPUs do definitely support AVX-512F, but not GFNI.  That was new in Ice Lake (https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/sunny_cove#New_instructions).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked, and indeed, it does not support GFNI.@PeterCordes